# What is JCasc / Job DSL option for "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket" flag?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-job-dsl, jcasc

I am trying to use jenkins [helm chart](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts) that uses Jcasc and JobDSL for job configuration.
I have configured organizationFolder with bitbucket config inside that traverses my bitbucket repos and creates multibranchPipeline jobs. Looks good and receives webhooks from bitbucket but does not trigger jobs.

```
ue Nov 02 14:49:53 UTC 2021] Received com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.hooks.PushHookProcessor$1 
UPDATED event from 10.0.0.112 ⇒ http://zzzzzzzzz:8080/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify with timestamp Tue Nov 02 14:49:53 UTC 2021
Connecting to https://bitbucket.org using zzzzzzzzzz/******
Repository type: Git
Looking up bddevteam83/infra-system for branches
Checking branch master from zzzzzzzzzzz/zzzzzz-system
      'Jenkinsfile' found
    Met criteria
Changes detected: master (null → d57b19309533ffd5133f88eb3809d1ad3896bfc8)
Did not schedule build for branch: master
```

I suspect it happens due to unchecked

"**Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket**" flag in multibranchPipeline config.

[image]

**QUESTION**: which JobDSL option enables "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket" flag?

my config is based on [this example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/master/demos/jobs/bitbucket.yaml) and looks like this

```
                organizationFolder('bitbucket') {
                    description("Bitbucket organization folder configured with JCasC")
                    displayName('bitbucket')

                    properties {
                        noTriggerOrganizationFolderProperty {
                            branches('develop')
                        }
                    }

                    // "Projects"
                    organizations {
                        bitbucket {
                            serverUrl("https://bitbucket.org/")
                            repoOwner("zzzzzzzzzzz")
                            credentialsId("bitbucket-http")
                            // "Traits" ("Behaviours" in the GUI) that are "declarative-compatible"
                            traits {
                                webhookRegistrationTrait {
                                    mode('ITEM')
                                }
                                submoduleOptionTrait {
                                    extension {
                                        disableSubmodules(false)
                                        recursiveSubmodules(true)
                                        trackingSubmodules(false)
                                        reference(null)
                                        timeout(null)
                                        parentCredentials(true)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // "Traits" ("Behaviours" in the GUI) that are NOT "declarative-compatible"
                    // For some 'traits, we need to configure this stuff by hand until JobDSL handles it
                    // https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-45504
                    configure { node ->
                        def traits = node / navigators / 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMNavigator' / traits
                        // Discover branches
                        traits << 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BranchDiscoveryTrait' {
                            strategyId('1')
                            // Values
                            //  1 : Exclude branches that are also filed as PRs
                            //  2 : Only branches that are also filed as PRs
                            //  3 : All branches
                        }
                        traits << 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.SSHCheckoutTrait' {
                            credentialsId('bitbucket-git-ssh-key')
                        }
                        // Filter by name (with regular expression)
                        traits << 'jenkins.scm.impl.trait.RegexSCMSourceFilterTrait' {
                            regex('.*')
                        }
                        // Discover pull requests from origin
                        traits << 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.OriginPullRequestDiscoveryTrait' {
                            strategyId('1')
                            // Values
                            // 1 : Merging the pull request with the current target branch revision
                            // 2 : The current pull request revision
                            // 3 : Both the current pull request revision and the pull request merged with the current target branch revision
                        }
                        // Discover pull requests from forks
                        traits << 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.ForkPullRequestDiscoveryTrait' {
                            strategyId('1')
                            // Values
                            // 1 : Merging the pull request with the current target branch revision
                            // 2 : The current pull request revision
                            // 3 : Both the current pull request revision and the pull request merged with the current target branch revision
                            trustID('1')
                            // Values
                            // 0 : Everyone
                            // 1 : Forks in the same account
                            // 2 : Nobody
                        }

                        traits << 'jenkins.scm.impl.trait.RegexSCMHeadFilterTrait' {
                            regex('(master)|(develop)|(development)|(integration)|(release.*)')
                        }

                    }
                    // "Project Recognizers"
                    projectFactories {
                        workflowMultiBranchProjectFactory {
                            scriptPath 'Jenkinsfile'
                        }
                    }
                    // "Orphaned Item Strategy"
                    orphanedItemStrategy {
                        discardOldItems {
                            daysToKeep(30)
                            numToKeep(100)
                        }
                    }
                    // "Scan Organization Folder Triggers" : 1 day
                    // We need to configure this stuff by hand because JobDSL only allow 'periodic(int min)' for now
                    configure { node ->
                        node / triggers / 'com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger' {
                            spec('H H * * *')
                            interval(86400000)
                        }
                    }

//// the below config I added seems to have no effect on "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket"

                    configure { node ->
                        node / triggers / 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.BitBucketMultibranchTrigger' {
                          overrideUrl('')
                        }
                    }
                    configure { node ->
                        node / triggers / 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.BitBucketTrigger' {
                          overrideUrl('')
                        }
                    }

                }
```

UPD: configuring anything via Web UI is not an option, everything must be managed as code.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about using the *branches* method within *[properties.noTriggerOrganizationFolderProperty](https://github.com/jenkinsci/branch-api-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/jenkins/branch/NoTriggerOrganizationFolderProperty/help-branches.html)* that

> Allows you to control the SCM commit trigger coming from branch
> indexing

```
organizationFolder(...) {
  ...
  properties {
    noTriggerOrganizationFolderProperty {
      // automatically trigger builds for branches matching this regex at index time
      branches('PR-\\d+')
    }
  }
```

[image: noTriggerOrganizationFolderProperty "branches" docs]